# Raspberry 1, no wifi dongle detected (TP-Link TL-WN823N)

Tags: usb, connection, wifi

I just bought a wifi dongle: TP-Link TL-WN823N, because it was supposed to work out of the box with the rasberry.

So, I have tried raspbian and now I am trying with OSMC.

First of all, if the raspberry is turned on and I connect the dongle it reboots. But it seems that is ok. So, here we are ok.

But then, booting the RPi with the dongle connected to the USB I got no wifi.
(Note: all the output is the same for my actual os (OSMC) than for the raspbian)

```
$ iwconfig  
lo        no wireless extensions.  
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Then, I just check connected usbs:

```
$ lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc.  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. LAN9500     Ethernet 10/100 Adapter / SMSC9512/9514 Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I know that the guy with no name: **Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109** it is the wifi dongle. But I have no clue how to make it recognize.
I tried this: https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Before I write the post, the quicker I find the solution.

I got the good and functional answer from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148389

Simply, I **needed to install the driver**. It seems that is pretty new and it is not included in the kernel (even in a lot of places they recommend this dongle to use it with the RPi).

Anyway, in case the link dies, you can get the drivers from here: http://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

Comment: How did you install the driver in rpi ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with the same device that you are talking about

Step 1: 
Install the driver using the link:

wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/install-wifi.tar.gz

tar xzf install-wifi.tar.gz

Step 2:Type this to just check the installation

./install-wifi -h

you are good to go.

this has been used by taking help from the link:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148389

Comment: Do you happen to still have the script? The Dropbox link is dead now. Thanks

Comment: @xtian777x This article may help you: http://blog.junaid.site/2017/07/11/tl-wn823n-driver-in-raspberry-pi-2-b/

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
apt-get install wicd
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade # This may take a little while. Be patient.

wget http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi # That's an O not Zero

chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi

install-wifi -h

install-wifi # This may take a little while. Be patient.
```

vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
### Add these lines at the end ###
network={
ssid="YOUR_WIFI_ROUTER"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="YOUR_PRE-SHARED-KEY"
}
```

vi /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf

```
#### Change line to look like this ####
options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0 rtw_ips_mode=1
```