# How to install diver for TL WN823N wifi adapter

Tags: wifi, kernel, driver

[I know this question might be marked as a duplicated - but the point is that previous solutions didn't work for me...]

**Wifi Adapter:** TP Link WN823N (EU) V2

**Device:** Raspberry Pi Zero Kernel 4.4.50+

**Problem:** Raspbian does not recognize the adapter. I tried to install the driver from the vendor, but they are supported only on Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10)

Is there a way I could compile and run them on my distro? Or where can I find a distro of raspbian with the proper kernel?

More Info:
Here is reported to works with raspbian http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters

Comment: Did you see this topic:
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54716/raspberry-1-no-wifi-dongle-detected-tp-link-tl-wn823n ?

Comment: I had seen only the link to the compiled version (that is dead) but didn't notice that there was also a guide to compile. Using this https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki to compile the rtl8192eu https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver driver solved my problem.

Comment: Great :). Maybe you can answer yourself with some details.